# What's the expected behaviour when adding "tags" to the front matter in Eleventy posts.json?

Tags: eleventy

As far as I understood, adding a `tags="post"` inside the configuration file of a specific Eleventy directory, say "posts", adds the tag "post" to all the posts and creates the collections.post automatically. This doesn't seem to work for me, am I missing something? The only way I can iterate over a collections.post is if I either add the tag post per post (on each post front matter) or if I add a collection in .eleventy.js like so

```
eleventyConfig.addCollection("post", (collection) => {
  return collection.getFilteredByGlob("_posts/*.md");
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on what you mean by "configuration file of a specific Eleventy directory". To specify data for a directory, see the guide here, https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-template-dir/, and scroll to Directory Data File. In theory you could add a JSON file named posts.11tydata.json inside the posts folder and set it up like so:

```
{
"tags":"post"
}
```

I'm mostly sure this works - testing now. ;)

Comment: And now you have access to collections.post, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Typing more characters cuz I have to.

Comment: I've found out why it was not working. Happens that I had other tags defined per post and the tags defined in the directory data file were being ignored since deep merge was not being done. Setting ```eleventyConfig.setDataDeepMerge(true);``` in .eleventy.js solved it. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Nice - I don't think I've seen that in action before, thank you for sharing it!

Comment: @PedroB Solved it as well for me! +1